# exporting from hive to sqlsrver using sqoop

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop, sqoop2

im trying to export data from hive into an mssql server, i know that sqoop and the sql server are OK as I can export another table without issue.

The error that Im getting is:

> 14/06/19 14:48:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1403175168750_0031_m_000003_0,  Status : FAILED
>       Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: 'You may be harboring secret illusions about how you want to li... More for Virgo http://t.co/Jnt91NMNt5'
>       at StageFlumeTweets.__loadFromFields(StageFlumeTweets.java:236)
>       at StageFlumeTweets.parse(StageFlumeTweets.java:174)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
>       ... 10 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "You may be harboring     secret     illusions about how you want to li... More for Virgo http://t.co/Jnt91NMNt5"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>       at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
>       at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:540)
>       at StageFlumeTweets.__loadFromFields(StageFlumeTweets.java:228)
>       ... 12 more

The command im using to export the data is:

> sqoop export --verbose --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://xx;database=xx;username=xx;password=xx" --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/xx/twitter_bulk2/ --table StageFlumeTweets --input-fields-terminated-by ','

The file with the data in is just a tweetid and the text like so:

> 468751929271517185,RT @BestofScorpio: A woman may want you, but she doesnt need you.
>   468751929565130752,I'm gonna need to borrow someone's red lipstick for this

Answer (score 0):

You get a `NumberFormatException`.

It may be an overflow problem (given the size of `tweedid`). Is the corresponding field in Sql Server declared as `bigint`?